# Template files and file structure for website

Tags: php, html

I have a few template files (I believe this is what they are called) such as: head.php (here I keep all the info inside the `<head>`), nav-menu.php, and footer.php. I use php require_once to insert them wherever I need to.

My problem arises when I create a sub folder with files in it. Let's say myDomain.com/blog/blog-post1.php. then, If I want to use the templates I need to use ../head.php but it doesn't solve the problem because the code inside head.php is not executed correctly since all the links to the CSS for example also need the "../". I have resorted to creating another copy of the header, which I know is inefficient. Is there a better way to deal with this problem?

I have looked for answers here, but nothing seems to be the exact problem I am having. I hope somebody can help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use absolute paths in your stylesheet including. To avoid the PHP problem you can use the `dirname(__FILE__).'/head.php'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your include files always use full path from the file who calling it(the file writing the require)
so instead of

```
require_once('nav-menu.php');
```

use

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/nav-menu.php');
```

this example means the nav-menu.php is in the same location as the file who defined that require. if it's relative use relative:

```
 require_once(__DIR__ . '/../nav-menu.php'); //nav-menu.php located one folder up from the calling file
```

this way it will work from any path you will call your file.

about your css and js links you can always use `/` at the beginning of the path which means the source is always relative to the root of the site url.

so instead of this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main/app.css" />
```

use this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main/app.css" />
```

which means the this file is in http://yourdomain/css/main/app.css
and this work from everywhere

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to be a close solution to the problem. Now, the problem is different. When I use require_once(__DIR__ . '/../nav_menu.php'); it works, but within nav_menu I have several links, for example index.php. if the file where I put the require_once is this: mySite.com/blog/post1.php then it looks for index.php within the blog folder and not mySite.com/index.php

Comment: If you use my rule it won't happened - or maybe i didn't get you - you should always include your php with full path - meaning with __DIR__ from the current location you are at. then from every location you will call this file it will still work

Comment: Once again, thanks. I was able to make it work on the server, but not locally. Would you mind explaining to me how I can set up WAMP to work with this type of configuration?

Comment: Nevermind... I got it to work. I just needed to create a virtual host on WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Reference public links and assets from your document root. i.e. start them with a preceding slash.

Imagine head.html and nav.html were includes.

head.html

```
<head>
    <link href="/static/css/example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

nav.html

```
<nav>
    <a href="/foo/bar">Bar</a>
    <a href="/foo/baz">Baz</a>
    <a href="/foo/bat">Bat</a>
</nav>
```

If you were on example.com/foo or example.com/foo/bat, all links would still work, as they are absolute.

You may forgo some flexibility of relative links, but you'll have fewer headaches.

If you were using apache as your web server with mod php.  You could set your include path for the environment.

In .htaccess

```
php_value include_path ".:/path/to/includes"
```

Then inside any of your Php files, you could easily reference your includes:

```
include 'head.html';
include 'nav.html';
// other stuff
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please elaborate a little bit more? It is still confusing.

Comment: I've placed the paths in html examples.